# MySQL does not read all massive data in csv file using load data infile

Tags: mysql

I have a total of 6077 data. However after running this command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '..admin staff.csv' INTO TABLE `adstaff` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The total data read is 1 mil++. But when I check my database it only contains 4033 real data and any other row after were null.

I am utterly confuse with another 2000++ data whereabouts because it does not came out when I do manual searching. I hope anyone can help me out thank you

Comment: Can you see anything special in the data file around line 4033?

Comment: Nope, similar with other line. Not even an additional accidental column

Comment: have you tried \r\n

Comment: I did it only insert the first line of data